# MySQL Query Optimization - Sub Queries + Multiple Joins

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, query-optimization

How can I optimize this query? It takes 2-3 seconds to get 10 rows.

```
SELECT users.user_id, users.user_name, users.user_display_name,
(SELECT COUNT(tweet_id) FROM tweets WHERE tweet_user_id = users.user_id AND tweet_status = 1) AS  user_tweets_count,
(SELECT COUNT(tweet_reply_id) FROM tweets_reply tr JOIN tweets t ON t.tweet_id = tr.tweet_reply_tweet_id WHERE tweet_reply_user_id = users.user_id AND t.tweet_status = 1 AND tr.tweet_reply_status = 1) AS user_replies_count
FROM users
JOIN tweets ON tweets.tweet_user_id = users.user_id
JOIN tweets_reply ON tweets_reply.tweet_reply_user_id = users.user_id
WHERE (tweets_reply.tweet_reply_status = 1 AND tweets.tweet_status = 1)
GROUP BY users.user_id
ORDER BY (user_tweets_count + user_replies_count) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: You don't need the subquery, just the count(tweet_id), count(tweet_reply_id) in the fields list (You're already joining the tables).

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT users.user_id, users.user_name, users.user_display_name, 
   COUNT(tweets.tweet_id) AS user_tweets_count, 
   COUNT(tweets_reply.tweet_reply_id) AS user_replies_count
   FROM users
   JOIN tweets ON tweets.tweet_user_id = users.user_id
   JOIN tweets_reply ON tweets_reply.tweet_reply_user_id = users.user_id
   WHERE (tweets_reply.tweet_reply_status = 1 AND tweets.tweet_status = 1)
   GROUP BY users.user_id
   ORDER BY (user_tweets_count + user_replies_count) DESC
   LIMIT 10
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Reference 'user_tweets_count' not supported (reference to group function) :(